# How can I copy/move a file from a folder to another with RGSS?

Tags: ruby, rpg-maker-xp

I've been trying to do this but I can only find Ruby answers. I'm trying to move or copy a file from, say, `Game Directory/Graphics/Pictures/file.png` to `Game Directory/file.png`. How can I do this in RGSS?

Comment: And why can't you work with those mentioned Ruby answers? RGSS is just a library, but still uses Ruby. Or what exactly are you looking for as opposed to Ruby answers?

Comment: Because I'm using RPG Maker XP. I've tried the solutions, but things used in them - like FileUtils - aren't included in RPG Maker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found two answers. The first one, way simpler and the one I'm going to use is just using `File.rename(from, to)`.

The second solution, a bit more complicated for the simple and one-use action I wanted to do, is to add [the FileUtils module](https://github.com/wachunga/rmxp-auto-font-install/blob/master/demo/Data/fileutils.rb) to your scripts, then use `FileUtils.mv(from, to)`.

Comment: just to clarify for anyone else reading this. File.rename will move the file, not copy it.